# How to delete worksheets except those on a list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 13 sheets. I'm trying to delete some of those worksheets.

I defined a list with the name of all sheets I want to keep. I am trying to make a condition so sheets with a name different from those in the list are deleted.

```vb
Sub PREPARE_FILE()

    Dim ws As Variant
    ws = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3") 'Reminder that the Workbook has 13 sheets total.

    For Each ws In Sheets(ws)
        If ws <> [SOMETHING] Then
        Delete = True
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

What could I replace [SOMETHING] with, or how could it be designed differently?

Comment: You want to delete `Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Didn't read properly, and only now I see you trying to *keep* those sheets. If so, then try:

```
Sub PREPARE_FILE()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (IsNumeric(Application.Match(ws.Name, arr, 0))) Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we want to **retain** Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3; give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim i As Long, nm As String, tot As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    tot = Sheets.Count
    
    For i = tot To 1 Step -1
        nm = Sheets(i).Name
        If nm = "Sheet1" Or nm = "Sheet2" Or nm = "Sheet3" Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            If Sheets.Count <> 1 Then
                Sheets(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note:

The `If Sheets.Count <> 1 Then` is there to prevent **all** sheets being deleted if there are no sheets meeting the "save" criteria.

Answer (score -1):

### Delete Sheets With Exceptions

- The first procedure, `deleteSheetsUsage`, illustrates how to use the second (main) procedure, `deleteSheets`.
- The third procedure, `TESTdeleteSheetsExpected`, tests the expected behavior of the second procedure. To run the test, add a new workbook containing sheets `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. Copy at least the second and third procedure into an added standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- The fourth procedure, `Result`, just shows the expected result of the third procedure in the `Immediate` window.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteSheetsUsage()
    Const SheetNames As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Keepers() As String
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
End Sub

Sub deleteSheets( _
    aWorkbook As Workbook, _
    SheetsToKeep() As String)

    Const ProcName As String = "deleteSheets"
    On Error GoTo clearError

    If Not aWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Evaluate LBound(SheetsToKeep)
        If Err = False Then ' 'If Not Err Then' doesn't work!
            On Error GoTo clearError
            If UBound(SheetsToKeep) >= LBound(SheetsToKeep) Then
                With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    Dim sh As Object
                    For Each sh In aWorkbook.Sheets
                        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
                            SheetsToKeep, 0)) Then
                            .Item(sh.Name) = Empty
                        Else
                            ' Sheet name found in SheetsToKeep.
                            ' No action taken.
                        End If
                    Next sh
                    Select Case .Count
                        Case 0
                            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                                & "No sheets to delete. " _
                                & "No action taken."
                        Case Is < aWorkbook.Sheets.Count
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                            aWorkbook.Sheets(.Keys).Delete
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                            If .Count > 1 Then
                                Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                                    & "Deleted " & .Count & " sheets."
                            Else
                                Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                                    & "Deleted 1 sheet."
                            End If
                        Case Else ' Case Is >= aWorkbook.Sheets.Count
                            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                                & "Attempted to delete too many sheets. " _
                                & "No action taken."
                    End Select
                End With
            Else
                ' ('UBound(SheetsToKeep) gt LBound(SheetsToKeep)').
                Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                    & "'Sheets To Keep Array' is empty. " _
                    & "No action taken."
            End If
        Else
            On Error GoTo clearError
            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                & "'Sheets To Keep Array' is only declared. " _
                & "No action taken."
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
            & "Workbook not defined ('Nothing'). " _
            & "No action taken."
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub

Sub TESTdeleteSheetsExpected()
    
    ' Test "Workbook not defined ('Nothing')."
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Keepers() As String
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
    
    ' Test "'Sheets To Keep Array' is only declared."
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
    
    ' Test "'Sheets To Keep Array' is empty."
    Dim SheetNames As String
    SheetNames = ""
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
    
    ' Test multiple sheets OK.
    wb.Worksheets.Add Count:=2
    SheetNames = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
    
    ' Test one sheet OK.
    wb.Worksheets.Add
    SheetNames = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers
    
    ' Test 'No sheets to delete.'
    SheetNames = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers

    ' Test 'Attempting to delete too many sheets.'
    SheetNames = "Sheet100"
    Keepers = Split(SheetNames, ",")
    deleteSheets wb, Keepers

End Sub

Sub Result()
    'deleteSheets': Workbook not defined ('Nothing'). No action taken.
    'deleteSheets': 'Sheets To Keep Array' is only declared. No action taken.
    'deleteSheets': 'Sheets To Keep Array' is empty. No action taken.
    'deleteSheets': Deleted 2 sheets.
    'deleteSheets': Deleted 1 sheet.
    'deleteSheets': No sheets to delete. No action taken.
    'deleteSheets': Attempted to delete too many sheets. No action taken.
End Sub
```